# Cannot set foreign key relationship

Tags: c#, entity-framework, foreign-keys

I'm trying to create a foreign key relationship in my code. I have:

```
site.Address.CountryID = svm.Address.Country.CountryId;
```

where Country is a particular country with a Name and a CountryId. The site.Address.CountryID is being used, rather than just the Country entity, because I want to just set the CountryID foreign key.

However, when I run this, I get the following error:

> The property 'CountryID' is part of the object's key information and cannot be modified.

I'm guessing I need a CountryID on my Address entity to hold a reference to the Country entity and not as an ID within the Country entity itself. I never want to create any new countries in code - this DB table simply holds a list of countries from which the user can select.

What am I doing wrong? Any code you need posting just shout.

Comment: Is 'CountryID ' Primary Key on Country Table ?

Comment: Does `Address` have a primary key? If not, then your question is a duplicate of [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4619564/247702).

Comment: Yes CountryID is a primary key on the Country table. Along with a string Name.

Comment: Address does have a primary key.