# Entity Framework: Insert a new record and Update information of this record

Tags: entity-framework-4

I don't know how I can handle this situation, Can you help me ?

a. **I insert a new record to a table**

```
var news = new News();

News.Title = "Hello World";

myRepository.InsertNews(catId,news);
```

In InsertNews() function, I call myDbContext.SaveChanges(); and new record is inserted into database. In this time, I already have Id of new record.

b. **After I have id of new records**, I need do call other functions to process some business and get data back to update new record.

```
news.Metadata = newData;
```

and I call myDbContext.SaveChanges();

My system displays an error message.
**The property 'Id' is part of the object's key information and cannot be modified.**

Please help me resolve this issue. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Look at this thread :

[The property 'Id' is part of the object's key information and cannot be modified](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3187963/the-property-id-is-part-of-the-objects-key-information-and-cannot-be-modified)