# "The property 'Modified' is part of the object's key information and cannot be modified

Tags: c#, entity-framework, orm, entity-framework-6.1

I am trying to change a field in my row using EF 6.1 and I am receiving the following error:

> The property 'Modified' is part of the object's key information and
>   cannot be modified.

However modified is not the Primary Key, nor part of any compound PK.

however it is part of my search conditions.

```
var item = _src.Items.Where(x => x.Modified).OrderBy(x => x.DateModified).FirstOrDefault();
 ...
 MarkItemAsSynced(item)


    private void MarkItemAsSynced(Item item)
    {
        item.Modified = false;     
        _src.SaveChanges();        <<<< ERROR THORWN
    }
```

What could be causing this issue?

Just to confirm again, The Item `Modified' is NOT the PK.

The Table does have a defined PK.

Model Class:

```
    public partial class Item
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        ...
        public bool Modified { get; set; }            
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you show the `Item` class? Or perhaps are you setting up anything extra in a fluent way?

Comment: It may be mapped as a key if the model was generated from the database. If the table has no primary key defined, the generator will try to select the fields that should be used as a key.

Comment: Maybe this helps? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3187963/the-property-id-is-part-of-the-objects-key-information-and-cannot-be-modified

Answer (score 0):

It seemed to be a corrupt or incorrectly mapped Data model.

I fixed it by doing the following:

1. Deleted the tables in the .edmx model.
2. I then re-added the tables back.
3. Saved the model

After that it worked correctly.

My assumptions is that EF was somehow incorrectly mapping the Modified field to the OK in the database.