# The property 'InventoryItemID' is part of the object's key information and cannot be modified

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I can't add a new instance of the type InventoryItem because ChangeTracker thinks I modified the primary key. But it is as the constructor done.

On the other hand, I could add items without problem. But when I inserted it after creation of an InventoryItemType (that is a NavigationProperty of InventoryItem) it fails.

I searched, tried, updated EF from 5 to 6.1.1 and I surrended... I need your help

```
        InventoryItemType iit = new InventoryItemType
        {
            InventoryFamilyID = 12,
            Name = checkInPackage.Name,
            Provider = shippingDestination.RelatedWarehouse.Name,
            Reference = "Paquete nº " + checkInPackage.CheckInPackageId
        };


        this.inventoryItemTypeRepository.InsertOrUpdate(iit);
        this.inventoryItemTypeRepository.Save();

        InventoryItem ii = new InventoryItem
        {
            WarehouseID = checkInPackage.WarehouseID,
            Price = 0,
            InventoryItemTypeID = iit.InventoryItemTypeID
        };


        this.inventoryItemRepository.InsertOrUpdate(ii); // th
        this.inventoryItemRepository.Save();
```

The repository has:

```
    public void InsertOrUpdate(InventoryItem inventoryitem)
    {
        if (inventoryitem.InventoryItemID == default(int)) {
            // New entity
            context.InventoryItems.Add(inventoryitem);
        } else {
            // Existing entity
            context.Entry(inventoryitem).State = EntityState.Modified;
        }
    }
```

**EDITED WITH THE FIX:**

I had a bad definition about the relationship `InventoryItemType`  1 to `InventoryItem`  n

After doing this changes in InventoryItemType.cs it runs without errors:

```
    public InventoryItemType()
    {
        InventoryItems = new HashSet<InventoryItem>();
    }
    public virtual ICollection<InventoryItem> InventoryItems { get; set; }
```

In business logic side

```
    iit.InventoryItems.Add(
            new InventoryItem
            {
                WarehouseID = checkInPackage.WarehouseID,
                Price = 0,
                InventoryItemType = iit
            }
    );

    this.inventoryItemTypeRepository.InsertOrUpdate(iit);
    this.inventoryItemTypeRepository.Save();
```

Comment: What's the relationship between `InventoryItemType` and `InventoryItem` ? 1 to 1 ?

Comment: The relation is `InventoryItemType` 1 to `InventoryItem` n

Comment: Have you tried debugging the insert or update method and see if it is going into the right condition?

Comment: Yes I tried. It goes to the right conditions. The fact is that ChanteTracker fires on DbSet.Add method and identifies the entity `inventoryitem` as it has changed the primary key. But as you can see in code, I didn't set it.

Comment: finally was a mistake in my hand. I didn't reflect correctly the relationship. But, I don't understand why a bad relantiship definition causes the error about primary key...

Answer (score 1):

According to [this description](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3188653/1385614) and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3220748/1385614), Instead of setting `InventoryItemTypeID` set `InventoryItemType` in `InventoryItem` entity, maybe it works.

```
InventoryItem ii = new InventoryItem
{
    WarehouseID = checkInPackage.WarehouseID,
    Price = 0,
    InventoryItemType = iit
};
```

Comment: I tried it with the same results. I think could be because I didn't set the `private ICollection<InventoryItem>` in the InventoryItemType class

Comment: Post the definition of `InventoryItemType` and `InventoryItem` and their EF configurations.

Comment: is fixed as I've written in the question,