# The property " MandatID " is part of the key information of the object and can not be changed

Tags: c#, entity-framework, sql-server-2008, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm working on asp.net mvc 4 project and i'm using EntityFramework to connect to DataBase.
I have four table :

- Mandat:  primaryKey MandatID
- Commande: with composite primaryKey CommandeID, MandatID and foriengKey MandatID references to Mandat
- Article: with composite primaryKey ArticleID, MandatID and foriengKey MandatID references to Mandat
- LigneCommande (association table) : 
  with composite  primaryKey CommandeID, ArticleID, MandatID 
  and with foriengKey CommandeID, MandatID --> Commande
                      ArticleID, MandatID --> Article
                      MandatID --> Mandat

When I try to add or modify LigneCommande I had the folowing Exception:

> The property " MandatID " is part of the key information of the object
>   and can not be changed.

Comment: possible duplicate of [The property 'Id' is part of the object's key information and cannot be modified](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3187963/the-property-id-is-part-of-the-objects-key-information-and-cannot-be-modified)

Comment: The property "MandatID" can be dublicated but the primaryKey is unique. also when i insert into LigneCommande using sql statement it works but when i use linq it doesn't work