# Entity Framework Update Key

Tags: sql, entity-framework

```
[Table("tblClients")]
public class ClientsTbl
{ 
    [DatabaseGeneratedAttribute(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int ClientID { get; set; }
    [Key]
    public int userid { get; set; }
}
```

If i have old data (from unknown source) to import which has userid that related with other tables for example invoice etc without using Foreign Key, how can i design my DB model? 
 If i would design like that insert must be like that :

```
Random a = new Random();
ClientsTbl c = new ClientsTbl()
{ 
    userid = a.Next(-1000, -1),  
}  
dataContext.Clients.Add(c); 
dataContext.SaveChanges(); 
var client = dataContext.Clients.FirstOrDefault(x => x.userid == c.userid); 
if(client!=null) 
{ 
    client.userid = c.ClientID; 
} 
dataContext.SaveChanges();
```

after inserting a record I need to update "userid" : 
`` 
 And it gives an error

> *The property 'userid' is part of the object's key information and cannot be modified.*

If i would change all operations to Stored Procedure's (insert and update) everything is ok.

Why Entity Framework doesn't allow to update Key ? (Sql server does)

Answer (score 0):

This is due to the fact that you're referencing the same object. This has been asked before and answered here:

[The property 'Id' is part of the object's key information and cannot be modified](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3187963/the-property-id-is-part-of-the-objects-key-information-and-cannot-be-modified)

I hope this helps you.

Comment: There is no Foreign Key in my problem. And your link doesn't include reliable solution to this problem.
Only way to pass this , using stored procedure. (I think, because i solved by this way)

Answer (score 0):

OO paradigm has this thing about "object identity".  RM does not have this (not in the sense that every identifier of a thing MUST MANDATORILY remain unchanged during the whole lifetime of the thing it identifies).

Tools that attempt to bridge the gap between the two are therefore inevitably faced with a kind of mismatch, and must do one of two things to address it : (a) break the OO paradigm of cast-in-concrete-immutable identity, or (b) enforce the OO paradigm and rule out perfectly legitimate RM operations.

Most if not all of them opt for (b) because that is the easiest way out, at least for the developers.

Comment: I think there isn't any philosofic problem. Very simple. EF is an object and it's rule to respect. Stored procedure is very good solutions. In fact i dont like to use EF but some security limitations force us to use EF.
I just wonder ıs there a eficient solutions.
Anyway many thanks your great answer.