# The property 'AccountNumber' is part of the object's key information and cannot be modified

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I'm using code first Entity Framework (code-first) in my application.

When I try to add a NEW object and save it to the database, EF is throwing this error.

> The property 'AccountNumber' is part of the object's key information
>   and cannot be modified.

First thing that is confusing about this error is AccountNumber is not a primary key in that table.

After reading a few posts to solve this, I try to create a brand new object just before it saves it like this:

```
public void CreateCustomerLookUp(CustomerLookUp customerLookUp)
    {
        //To avoid EF specific error recreating object using NEW - wierd!
        //http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3187963/the-property-id-is-part-of-the-objects-key-information-and-cannot-be-modified

        customerLookUp.LastUpdated = DateTime.Now;

        var encryptedCustomerLookUp = EncryptCustomerLookUp(customerLookUp);

        var newCustomerLookup = new CustomerLookUp()
        {
            AccountNumber = encryptedCustomerLookUp.AccountNumber,
            EmailAddress = encryptedCustomerLookUp.EmailAddress,
            MobileNumber = encryptedCustomerLookUp.MobileNumber,
            UmbracoMemberId = encryptedCustomerLookUp.UmbracoMemberId,
            UpdateCode = encryptedCustomerLookUp.UpdateCode,
            UpdateNotification = encryptedCustomerLookUp.UpdateNotification
        };

        customerDataContext.Entry(newCustomerLookup).State = EntityState.Added;//<< Throwing error here!
        customerDataContext.SaveChanges();
    }
```

I have also tried

```
customerDataContext.CustomerLookUps.Add(newCustomerLookup);
```

Instead of

```
customerDataContext.Entry(newCustomerLookup).State = EntityState.Added;
```

But I'm still getting the error. This is what my CustomerLookup entity looks like, I can't figure out why EF thinks AccountNumber is a Key its not. (I was thinking maybe primary key and key are two different things?)

```
    public class CustomerLookUp
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [StringLength(256)]
    public string AccountNumber { get; set; }

    [StringLength(256)]
    public string MobileNumber { get; set; }
    [StringLength(256)]
    public string EmailAddress { get; set; }
    [StringLength(256)]
    public string UpdateCode { get; set; }

    [StringLength(256)]
    public string UmbracoMemberId { get; set; }

    public bool UpdateNotification { get; set; }

    public DateTime LastUpdated { get; internal set; }
}
```

This is my context class only 2 DB-sets **THAT ARE NOT** linked. 
I have looked in the DB to see what gets generated and its two tables as expected. The other Entity "Customer" does have AccountNumber as the PK but I am not trying to save to that table.

```
public partial class CustomerContext : DbContext
{
    public CustomerContext()
        : base("name=CustomerContext")
    {
    }

    public DbSet<Customer> Customers { get; set; }
    public DbSet<CustomerLookUp> CustomerLookUps { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
    }



}
```

For completeness this is the Customer class. (This **has** AccountNumber as PK, but this is in a completely different table, and not one I am trying to save in too.

```
public class Customer
{
    [Key]
    [Required]
    [StringLength(256)]
    public string AccountNumber { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(256)]
    public string SupplyPostCode { get; set; }

    [StringLength(256)]
    public string Title { get; set; }

    [StringLength(256)]
    public string Forenames { get; set; }

    [StringLength(256)]
    public string Name { get; set; }



}
```

**UPDATE:** I have made progress, but not totally solved the problem. What I decided to do was Rename the columns so I had two different names in each table for AccountNumber in the CustomerLookUp class I changed the name to  AccountNumberX then run the cure again. I still got the same error. Which means for sure the problem was nothing to do with the entity I was trying to save. EF was complaining about the Customer Class.

Within the business logic that ultimately calls the CreateCustomerLookUp method I am retrieving a customer record and Decrypting it, I need to do this to read the plain text values, but I am not asking EF to save these changes.

So what is happening is when I am saving the newCustomerLookup object it is also trying to save the Decrypted version of the customer record that I retrieved earlier.

So the real question is, how do I tell EF I don't want it to save the changes made to that object? I only want to save the new newCustomerLookup object.

Comment: Can you check the primary key definition in the table in your database?

Comment: Please post the code for your CustomerDataContext.

Comment: Are you setting up the property as a key in your context class?

Comment: Checked the db... The customer look up table has not got Account as PK

Comment: Is the Exception thrown on `SaveChanges`? In debug mode check to see what the attached entities are on the DbContext of type `Customer` and see if any have a property `AccountNumber` that is being modified. Also is there a FK relationship between `Customer` and `CustomerLookup`?

Comment: There is no FK relationship and the error is NOT being thrown on saving changes, its on the line before.

Comment: There doesn't seem to be anything obvious with the code you've posted. It runs without error in a knocked up version. I don't believe there's enough information here to diagnose - too much guesswork at what else you're doing (e.g. how CreateCustomerLookUpis being called, what EncryptCustomerLookUp is doing, what prompted your 'wierd' comment). Please read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: @Tone - Check my update in the question, I have found the root of the problem

Comment: *I am retrieving a customer record and Decrypting it* Either get the customer with `AsNoTracking` or detach it from the context before adding the lookup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As explained in the answer by 'Tone' this error occurs because EF is trying to update all known entities that have changed, even if you do not explicitly call:

```
customerDataContext.Entry(newCustomerLookup).State = EntityState.Added;
customerDataContext.SaveChanges();
```

In my case the data that is stored in the DB is encrypted. In my business logic I need to un-encrypt a customer, perform some business logic then update a customerLookUp record. By un-encrypting the customer record I have effectively changed it, which is what causes the error when I try and save the customerLookup record.

**Solution:**

There are a few different ways to solve this problem. One way is to create a second data-context object. You would use the first one to get the record and un-encrypt it, and then the second one will be used to save the entity to the db. Though this works, I find it to be a bit of a messy solution.

Instead of un-encrypting the record that comes from the dbcontext, I copied the data as it is in to a new object. Then I un-encrypt that new object, this way I never change the record, so when I call saveChanges() the only changes EF will make are to the record I explicitly changed.

This concept is known as the "Data Transfer Object Pattern" you can read more about it here:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/data/using-web-api-with-entity-framework/part-5

https://www.exceptionnotfound.net/entity-framework-and-wcf-mapping-entities-to-dtos-with-automapper/

Answer (score 2):

Based on your update, you need to look at the lifetime of your `DbContext`. A `DbContext` will by default, track changes in any entities it's aware of then try to save those changes when you call `SaveChanges()`.

So what looks to be happening in this case is you're defining a `DbContext` somewhere, working with your `Customer`, then working with your `CustomerLookup`, all while the `DbContext` is active and aware of your entities (e.g. it will be aware of any entity you retrieve from the database). Then when you call `SaveChanges()` it's trying to save everything it knows has changed.

You generally want to create and dispose `DbContexts` only as you need them. They're lightweight and you'll typically want them to last for a unit of work (whatever that may be in your app). Get into the habit enclosing their use in `using` blocks to keep things clean. So your method might look something like:

```
public void CreateCustomerLookUp(CustomerLookUp customerLookUp)
{
    using (var context = new CustomerContext())
    {
        customerLookUp.LastUpdated = DateTime.Now;

        var encryptedCustomerLookUp = EncryptCustomerLookUp(customerLookUp);

        var newCustomerLookup = new CustomerLookUp()
        {
            AccountNumber = encryptedCustomerLookUp.AccountNumber,
            EmailAddress = encryptedCustomerLookUp.EmailAddress,
            MobileNumber = encryptedCustomerLookUp.MobileNumber,
            UmbracoMemberId = encryptedCustomerLookUp.UmbracoMemberId,
            UpdateCode = encryptedCustomerLookUp.UpdateCode,
            UpdateNotification = encryptedCustomerLookUp.UpdateNotification
        };

        context.Entry(customerLookUp).State = EntityState.Modified;
        context.CustomerLookUps.Add(newCustomerLookup);
        context.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

Notes:

1. You'll also need to make changes elsewhere in your code to similarly
   localize `DbContexts`. Making the above change alone will result in
   2 `DbContexts` being active so you may well still run into other
   tracking issues.
2. You could potentially restrict the scope even further within the
   method with a bit of refactoring. I've enclosed the whole method as
   I see you're updating 2 entities (`customerLookup` and
   `newCustomerLookup`) and I don't know what you're doing in
   `EncryptCustomerLookup`.

Comment: Great explanation, (voted it up) - I had worked out what was going on and at one point I did do what you suggested and had used a different dbcontext object to do the saving. - but yes I did come up against other tracking issues. So I came up with a different approach that solved this, so I will answer my own question and share the solution.