# How to ignore properties in Entity Framework 6 for Update?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I am currently trying to update using *Entity Framework 6* and am having some trouble ginven a **PK** property in my DB, which I DONT want to edit but cant find the correct way to ignore it.

```
myobj aux = new obj(){
//code
};

using (var context = new ModelEntity())
{
    var item = context.mytable.Find(id);
     context.Entry(item).CurrentValues.SetValues(aux);
     context.SaveChanges();
}
```

I get the error: The property 'xxxx' is part of the object's key information and cannot be modified. '

I have searched for some kind of ignore and have found nothing.
All I find are EF4  and 5.

Comment: Please show how you're setting up the Context to know about the objects. Are you using data attributes? Fluent syntax? The way you set up the property as the key depends on what approach you're using.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are trying to ignore properties in an entity, then you would need to add a [NotMapped] attribute to that property in the class. More documentation here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/included-properties

Also, it seems like the error presented is more to do with you attempting modify a Primary key or index. I see this is actually answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/12397981/1670574