# How to save list of same model in ASP.NET MVC 5 using Entity Framework 6 using iteration

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework-6, asp.net-mvc-5.2

**Controller**

```
public async Task<ActionResult> Create(BookingCost bookingCost)
{
    if(ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        var costWeightList = bookingCost.CostWeightLists.ToArray();
        foreach(var costWeight in costWeightList)
        {
            bookingCost.Cost = Convert.ToDecimal(costWeight.Cost);
            bookingCost.WeightId = costWeight.WeightId;
            db.BookingCost.Add(bookingCost); // GETTING ERROR ON 2nd ITERATION
            await db.SaveChangesAsync();
        }
        await db.SaveChangesAsync();
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }     
}
```

**Error**

> The property 'WeightId' is part of the object's key information and
>   cannot be modified.

**Trace**

```
Line 103:                    bookingCost.Cost = Convert.ToDecimal(costWeight.Cost);
Line 104:                    bookingCost.WeightId = costWeight.WeightId;
Line 105:                    db.BookingCost.Add(bookingCost);
Line 106:                    await db.SaveChangesAsync();
Line 107:                }
```

**Debug:**

Iteration 1

[image]

Iteration 2

[image]

First item is saved successfully in db, sencond time I am getting this error.

Comment: Are you meaning to add the `costWeight` to the db context? You are iterating through a property of `bookingCost`, but for each iteration you are adding the same `bookingCost` to the table. Entity Framework is preventing you from doing that.

Comment: @akerra, I am changing weight and cost and saving it in db.

Comment: try constructing a new `BookingCost` object within the loop and adding that to the context. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3187963/the-property-id-is-part-of-the-objects-key-information-and-cannot-be-modified

Comment: @akerra, seems like a good idea. I will do it now & let u know.

Comment: @akerra, Worked..  (y)