# entity framework change reference of a nested object

Tags: c#, entity-framework, dbcontext

it's a simple question but I can't seem to find a solution.
I have two classes as follows:

```
    public class Person{
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    [Key]
    public int Id{get;set;}
    public string Name {get;set;}
    public CarType Cartype {get;set;}
    }

    public class CarType{
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    [Key]
    public int Id{get;set;}       
    public string Type {get;set;}
    public string CompanyLocation {get;set;}
    }
```

Suppose I have two CarTypes as follows:

```
   1    Mercedes        Berlin          

   2    Chevrolet       Detroit
```

and I have a person as follows:

```
1 Mike 2 (2 is the foreign key to `CarType`)
```

the question is, how can I change the `CarType` for Mike to be 1(i.e. change the reference to another row in table `CarType`) ?

here is my code :

```
Person person = dbContext.Persons.Single(c => c.Id == 1);
CarType carType= dbContext.CarTypes.Single(c => c.Id == 1);
person.CarType= carType;
```

I tried answers found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3187963/the-property-id-is-part-of-the-objects-key-information-and-cannot-be-modified)

but I still get the same error upon doing `dbContext.SaveChanges()` which is :

> The property 'Id' is part of the object's key information and cannot
> be modified

The thing is I don't want to update it's referenced `CarType`, I want to change the reference to be to another row

Comment: Where is your code that is doing the update?  It sounds like that is wrong.

Comment: Can you add your attempt to the question?

Comment: @Neil I added it to the question

Comment: @JohnathanBarclay I edited the question and added my attempt to it

Comment: And how are your relationships configured? Is `CarType.Id` used as the foreign key to `Person`?

Comment: @JohnathanBarclay yes sure,I'm using code first migrations so the database would be generated as follows:-Person: Id (primary key), Name,  CarType_Id 
      -CarType: Id (Primary key), CompanyLocation,Type

Comment: Please ensure that the code you have provided is actually the code you are trying to run, not a simplified example as this simplification can hide something crucial to the problem you are having. I.e. your example field is "Cartype" but code refers to it as "CarType", a typo for sure, but shows it's not a copy-paste from your code. I suspect that this may be tied that your navigation property (CarType) is not marked as `virtual`. This is used for both lazy loading and change tracking so EF can track when you replace a reference. (something I need to test as I use virtual by default)

Answer (score 2):

Person should be like this

```
public class Person{
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    [Key]
    public int Id{get;set;}
    public string Name {get;set;}
    [ForeignKey("Cartype ")]
    public int CarTypeID{get;set;}
    public CarType Cartype {get;set;}
 }
```

after that you can make changes of CarType in Person object using
below code

```
person.CarTypeID= carType.Id;
dbContext.SaveChanges();
```